# Is this join overcomplicated?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have inherited an application made by a previous developer. Some of the database calls are running slow in places where there is a large amount of data.  I have found in general the SQL code is well written but there are places that make me think, 'what the..?'

Here is one example:

```
select a.*
from bs_ResearchEnquiry a 
left join bs_StateWorkflowState_Map b
on (
   select c.MapId from bs_StateWorkflowState_Map c 
   where c.StateId = a.StateId AND c.StateWorkflowId = a.StateWorkflowId
   )=b.MapId     
where
    b.IsFinal=1
```

- The `MapId` field is a unique primary key to the `bs_StateWorkflowState_Map` table.
- `StateId` and `StateWorkflowId` **together** also form a unique key.
- There will always be a match on these keys to rows in the foreign table `bs_ResearchEnquiry`

Therefore, could I rewrite the left join more efficiently, and safely, as:

```
inner join bs_StateWorkflowState_Map b
on b.StateId = a.StateId AND b.StateWorkflowId = a.StateWorkflowId
```

Or was the original developer trying to achieve something I've missed ?

Comment: UPDATE:  I have just tried the simpler join to find the opposite effect!  Execution time has increased from a few seconds to well over a minute. So although the original syntax appears over-engineered it could be the developer was using the most efficient method after all.   Not yet sure why this is the case.

Comment: have a look at the [query plan](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7359705/50552). Does performance improve if you keep the `left join`?

Comment: @Andomar yes, the left join does improve things.  
My syntax with Inner Join takes 90 seconds
My syntax with Left Join takes 45 seconds
The original syntax takes <5 seconds

My aim was to get it <2 seconds

Comment: Maybe I should change this question to, Why is the original complicated join faster than  the simplified version ?

Comment: It can only mean one of two things: 1) the optimizer is doing a bad job here, or 2) one of your three assumptions is wrong or not established by constraints (and hence not visible to the DBMS).

Comment: FINAL UPDATE:  The StateId and StateWorkflowId fields were indexed, but separately.  I replaced this with a compound index and performance has greatly increased to desirable levels.  Thanks for all the input

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your simplification looks good to me.  Note that the presence of:

```
where b.IsFinal = 1
```

Means that the `outer join` is effectively `inner join`.

Answer (score 0):

With your explanation on keys given, you are right, the query can be simplified. It selects records from `bs_ResearchEnquiry` where the associated `bs_StateWorkflowState_Map` record is final. So use `EXISTS`:

```
select *
from bs_ResearchEnquiry re
where exists
(
  select *
  from bs_StateWorkflowState_Map m
  where m.StateId         = re.StateId
    and m.StateWorkflowId = re.StateWorkflowId
    and m.IsFinal = 1
);
```

(From your explanation on uniqueness, I gather that there already exist indexes on `(StateId, StateWorkflowId)` in both tables. If not, create them.)

Comment: Well, in SQL Server multiple fields in `IN` clause are invalid. You can use `EXISTS` instead.

Comment: where (x, y) in ...  is not valid SQL

Comment: @Rokuto: Well, spotted. I always forget about this limitation in SQL Server, which really makes some  queries less readable. I'll update.

Comment: @userSteve: Not valid in SQL Server, but many DBMS support it and it makes for very readable queries. A pity that SQL Server lacks it. I'll update.